# Border not showing in CSS even after labeling them !important

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for this particular `div`:

```
.generated_text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    font-family:'Gudea' !important;
    text-align: left;
    color:#000 !important;
    background:#fff !important;
    border: 30px !important;
    border-color: #4b4b4b !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54%;
    left: 38.5%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:560px;
    height:170px;
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Note, I'm very new when it comes to web dev. Any help would be much appreciated and let me know if i'm missing anything in this post.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML. [mcve]

Comment: have you at least looked at what your browser page inspector says?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add
`border-style: solid`
or
`border: 30px solid #4b4b4b`

Answer (score 0):

For border to be shown, you need: width and style(dotted,solid etc). Maybe the color, but i'm not sure if the default one is black or you need to specify, too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must add `border-style: solid;` .
And you dont need `!important` , it is used only if you have more options for 1 propertie, f.e. you have

```
.generated_text{ color:#fff;}  div.generated_text{ color:#000;}
```

and class .generated_text is in div, color will be #000, but if you add `!important` in `.generated_text{ color:#fff !important;}` it will be "more important"-